# Цикл for(String url : urls) что означает запись в скобках?

Tags: java, циклы

Добрый день. Я новичок в java. Помогите понять, что означает запись в скобках цикла

```
for(String url : urls)
```

Похоже на тернарный оператор, но не знаю куда копать...

Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: если вы говорите о цикле, а в скобках у вас одна переменная в единственном числе, а вторая во множественном, да как вы думаете, что может означать запись такая?

Comment: @teran
"Цикл означать такая запись может,
И пусть Вас это больше не тревожит - 
Я не хочу печалить Вас ничем." 
Пушкин

Comment: такая конструкция по типу синтаксический сахар.. "эквивалентна"
`for(int i = 0; i < urls.lenght; i++){`  
`String url = urls[i];`  
`}`  
при условии, что urls массив, для коллекция аналог перебора элементов по коллекции